# will you come and follow me IF I BUT CALL your name: what's the meaning?

Tags: prepositions

I'm translating an English hymn to Italian, but I'm not sure about the meaning of the structure

> **If** + *subject* + **but** + *verb*

Is the sense "should (or would) call your name?" (uncertainty, possibility etc.)

or is it "everything except calling your name?" (exception etc.)

I'm an Italian native speaker and this is quite difficult for me.

Answer (score 5):

The word *but* is acting as an adverb here, modifying the verb *call*.

It could also be read:

> *If I only call your name*, or
>
> *If I simply call your name*

Answer (score 2):

["*But*" as an adverb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but#Adverb):

> Merely, only.
>
> *Since that day, my mood has changed but a little.*

Answer (score 0):

It means "if I call your name ..." another example:

> If I but touch His clothes, I shall be cured

Comment: this answer implies that the word "but" has no meaning at all and can be simply removed from the sentence and not change the meaning. That is incorrect.